# R igraph output vertice is not shown

Tags: r, igraph

I am using R igraph package to display gene networks. The plot on Rstudio is like this (I can't post image because I am new user and don't have enough reputation, sorry about that):

[R igraph on preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kriCE.png)

Now I want to draw this on file to clearly see the changes and there is always an issue on vertices near margin side like this:

[part of output pdf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NBwa.png)

My code is as follows`

```
pdf("graph.pdf",width = 20, height = 10)

par(mar = c(9,9,9,9))

plot(finalnet, edge.arrow.size=0.1, edge.curved=FALSE,vertex.size= 3, margin = -0.5)

dev.off()
```

Update: I have tried square layout and the problem persists, here is my plotting object and square plot.
[square plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CiXU.png)

[rda file for my igraph object](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aqrz0ATqYGkKgv9_O0fG1OsMVZ-Obw)

Can anyone give me an suggestion how to solve this issue? To whole net is about 170 vertices but I don't know why it cannot be displayed on output file well. I have tried different plot options in mai, mar but this seems to fail.

Comment: What does it look like when you try just `pdf("graph.pdf")` without specifying `width` and `height`?  You're specifying a rectangular size for a square object.  Also, if you post a `dput()` of your object, we may be able to do a better job helping you.

Comment: Please improve your question by **posting** your images rather than linking to it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting this behavior is because you are specifying `margin` in your plot call. `margin=-0.5` is telling R to extend the plot 0.5 units past the graphics device dimensions, below are three examples:

#### Your original plotting call, notice the clipping

```
pdf("withMargin.pdf")
par(mar=c(9,9,9,9))
plot(g, margin=-0.5)
dev.off()
```

[image]

#### Without the call to `par`, problem still presists but now youuse the entire dimension of the graphics device.

```
png("withoutPar_Margin.png")
#par(mar=c(9,9,9,9))
plot(g, margin=-0.5)
dev.off()
```

[image]

#### Lastly, removing the `margin` in `plot`

```
png("withoutplotMargin.png")
par(mar=c(9,9,9,9))
plot(g)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: I got this. it seems the only way to keep graph clean and edge visible is to use less node. Or they will bump together and extending edge will cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying a rectangular size for what looks like a square object. Try a square size, as in

```
pdf("graph.pdf")
```

This will use the defaults, which are square.

But, it's hard to know for sure since you haven't given us the object to troubleshoot for you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have uploaded the R object and it may help troubleshooting.